# MySQL 5.7 root password expired; can only run mysqld_safe on Mac

Tags: mysql

Upgraded to Yosemite and then re-installed MySQL as a suggestion for socket errors. Installed 5.7 and added `pdo_mysql.default_socket=/tmp/mysql.sock` to /etc/php.ini.default.

After changing the password for root, it was set as expired and now can't do anything without being in safe mode with `--skip-grant-tables`. Getting message:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

when trying to run MySQL on Terminal without "skipping grant tables". Changing to `password_expired=N` is not allowed with this option on. Is there another way to set it to PASSWORD EXPIRE NO (or even better, NEVER)?

Due to software incompatibilities, I can not upgrade to El Capitan.

Comment: I think I screwed up the settings by failing to flush privileges after setting the password.

Comment: Fixed this by removing 5.7.11 and its data files and reinstalling 5.6.29. Looks like two versions of files were getting mixed up.